# How can we know it is better to compress some data with an algorithm based on our previous experience of a similar type of data?

Tags: statistics, information-theory

In practice, people use the same type of compression algorithm for similar data from a similar source. Why can we compress different pictures with the same compression algorithm, and it works for all? Is it because of a statistical or information-theoretic property of the data, and if it is, what is that property?

Comment: An algorithm that worked for only one picture wouldn't be much of an algorithm.

Comment: @RobertIsrael sure, yes. However, how can we know it will work for another picture? We can instinctively say to data from a similar source is similar. Is there any way to measure similarity based on the property of the information in those pictures?

Comment: The algorithm might be able to compress most pictures occuring in the practice, but it is impossible to compress every picture. Google "Kolmogorov complexity" for more details.

Comment: I do not think that we can know in advance whether the algorithm will work also for another picture.

Comment: @Peter I indeed work on computer programs, and I want to formally describe there will be similar constructs (or patterns) that occur in computer programs with similar semantics when compressed with the same algorithm.

Comment: Most picture compression is lossy compression--you cannot recover the exact original bits of the file--and it relies on observations about human perception of pictures. It assumes we don't care (much) about the information that is lost. I don't think this assumption is valid for compression of computer programs.

Comment: As for what you want to formally describe about compression of computer programs, I have doubts that it is true. Even if the compression algorithm does not _deliberately_ encrypt the data (as some do), a good algorithm will adapt to the data it has so that the exact same block of code could be encoded in a very different way depending on what else is in the input file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's compresson and then there's compression. Say a compression algorithm is *lossless* if there exists a decompression routine that will return *exactly* te original file, for any file. Conversely, an algorithm is *lossy* if it  is not lossless. Typical flavors of jpeg are lossy, for example:  When you convert an image to jpeg in a graphics program you get to choose a compression ratio;  more compression gives a smaller jpeg but it looks  less like the original.

Never mind lossy compression for now; an explanation of why that works at all would involve talking about how visual perception works. Regarding lossless compression: How can we know it works on all files? We can't know that, in fact we do know just the opposite:

> > **Obviousness.** There does not exist a lossless compression algorithm that decreases the size of every non-empty file.

Proof: say $C(f)$ is the compressed version of the file $f$. Suppose $f$ and $g$ are  one-byte files with $f\ne g$. Then $C(f)$ and $C(g)$ are both zero-byte files, so $C(f)=C(g)$; hence $C$ is not one-to-one.

So why *do* compression algorithms work in practice? They take advantage of  redundancies common to the files being compressed.

For example, the sort of image files  that are often converted to gif typically involve blocks of solid color. Which is to say there's a lot of repetition in thhe bit pattern, making "run-length encoding" useful:

Say the file contains the string "0000000000111110000000". One can easily concoct a format that says "ten zeroes, then five ones, then seven more zeroes" in  less than 22 bytes.

Comment: Even more obvious: you can't decrease the size of a $0$-byte file.  But slightly less trivial: given any $n \ge 1$, there is no lossless algorithm that decreases the size of every $n$-byte file.